# Cypher Invalid Query with IN operator results in CypherTypeException but Java driver swallows it

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is on *Cypher 1.8.2*

I have the following query that works OK:

```
START person=node:personsindex('*:*') 
WHERE person.name IN ['Peter', 'Michael'] 
RETURN  person;
```

When run in Java, with:

```
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine;
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionResult;
....
ExecutionEngine engine...
ExecutionResult result = this.engine.execute(query);
```

Provided I do have the data in my graph, I get results:

```
assertEquals("Columns :", 1, result.columns().size());
Iterator<Node> personNodes = result.columnAs("person");
assertTrue("Should have some results", personNodes.hasNext())
```

If my query becomes:

```
START person=node:personsindex('*:*') 
WHERE person.name IN 'Peter' // I know I should not do it like this
RETURN  person;
```

I get the following exception on the shell, which is good:

```
CypherTypeException: Literal expected to be of type Collection but it is of type String
```

But when I run it in Java, the exception is swallowed and I get a columnSet back,
but with no data:

```
ExecutionResult result = this.engine.execute(query);

assertEquals("Columns :", 1, result.columns().size());
Iterator<Node> personNodes = result.columnAs("person");
assertFalse("No results", personNodes.hasNext())
```

Is this expected behaviour?